# Wordpress Plugin Development, find specific page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to develop a plugin, and I'm not the best at developing plugins. I do ofc know php, and oop, but the wp functions is pretty difficult to understand, and also the codex.

I'm trying to make an "ORDERS" page, where you can click on a button, to go to `view_order.php` where it will fetch all the data from the specific ID.

I got it all to work, to fetch out of the right table etc, but the problem is, that i have a `<a href` like this:

```
<a href="view_order.php?id=<?php echo $row->id; ?> ">
```

(It finds the id, so no problems there) but when i click on it, it will go to

> http://localhost/wp-admin/view_order.php?id=3

and ofc say that it can't find the page. I'm a bit confused here. What can i do?

Answer (score 0):

Where is your view_order.php file located ?  Is it accessible in the front end I mean http://localhost/view_orders.php?id=3  ?.

If so you can try putting the absolute URL in the link, by getting the site url using site_url() function.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a small mistake while building the link, which can be easily fixed. Imagine you have an anchor looking like this:

```
<a href="path/to/file.php?option=8&dummy=t">Click me!</a>
```

When you are currently on `mysite.com/admin/`, you will get redirected to `mysite.com/admin/path/to/file.php?option=8&dummy=t`. This happens because you are missing a leading slash (`/`) within your link, which would make the path in the link relative to the **site root**, instead of it being relative to the **current page**.
So the solution is quite simple: Add a leading slash (`/`) to the `href` attribute on your anchor:

```
<a href="/path/to/file.php?option=8&dummy=t">Click me!</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

with Wordpress I prefer using absolute urls.

try to do your urls like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>view_order.php?id=<?php echo $row->id; ?> ">
```

that will pickup the site url from the wordpress settings.
so when you put the site live you don't have to worry about changing the urls later.